# How can i add a calculated column to a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to add a column to a grid that displays an amount equal to another column if its past due

This is what i currently have:

```
xgrdvLgCustomerInvoice.Columns.Add("Past Due", System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal"), "xgcCurrentAmount")
```

this is what i found online but it says it .add does not take 3 arguments.

how can i add this column without it being bound to a data source?

Comment: I would add the column from the start, set it's width to zero to hide it, and then show it if needed.

Comment: how would i display the data that i need

Comment: inside that grid column (let's say its the 4th column of the grid) place a TextBlock and name it; <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Grid.Column="3" />. 
Now set myTextBlock.Text property from the code-behind file.